# Handling subquery in a Kotlin Exposed framework

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-exposed

Is Exposed 0.27.1 capable to translate the following SQL statement?

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName,
   (SELECT COUNT(O.Id)
    FROM "Order" O
    WHERE O.CustomerId = C.Id) AS OrderCount
FROM Customer C;
```

Here is what I tried but unfortunately the subquery works independently to the rest of the query.

```
val query = Customer
    .leftJoin(Order, { Customer.id }, { Order.customerId })
    .slice(
            Customer.firstName,
            Customer.lastName,
            intLiteral(Order
                    .innerJoin(Customer, { Order.customerId }, { Customer.id })
                    .slice(Order.id.count())
                    .select { Order.customerId eq Customer.id }
                    .first()[Order.id.count()].toInt())//.alias("OrderCount")
    )
    .selectAll()
```

Besides, if that would be possible then how I could use the alias to fetch result from the ResultRow? Following [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59887257/6154432) it seems that the solution would be to store the entire subquery with an `alias()` method call in a single variable but that will look ugly. Is there any better way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Official F.A.Q. states that the only way to have subqueries is [via alias for inner query](https://github.com/JetBrains/Exposed/wiki/FAQ#q-how-can-i-implement-nested-queries):

```kotlin
val orderCount = Order.customerId.count().alias("OrderCount")
val subQuery = Order.slice(Order.customerId, orderCount)
                    .selectAll()
                    .groupBy(Order.customerId)
                    .alias("subQuery")
val query = Join(Customer)
                    .join(subQuery, JoinType.LEFT, subQuery[Order.customerId], Customer.id)
                    .slice(Customer.firstName, Customer.lastName, subQuery[orderCount])
                    .selectAll()
```

But maybe you don't need subqueries here? This one generates a bit different SQL-query with almost same query result (in contrast with the previous one, if there were no orders for customer, it will return 0 instead of null):

```kotlin
val query = Customer
            .leftJoin(Order, { Customer.id }, { Order.customerId })
            .slice(Customer.firstName, Customer.lastName, Order.id.count().alias("OrderCount"))
            .selectAll()
            .groupBy(Customer.id)
```

Generated SQL:

```sql
SELECT CUSTOMER."firstName",
       CUSTOMER."lastName",
       COUNT("ORDER".ID) OrderCount
FROM CUSTOMER
LEFT JOIN "ORDER" ON CUSTOMER.ID = "ORDER"."customerId"
GROUP BY CUSTOMER.ID
```

Answer (score 6):

Previous answer don't generate subquery in select clause. The way that describe below allowed it. This is tested on **Exposed 0.36.2**.

#### SQL

Next example executes SQL:

```
SELECT "groups".id, "groups".name,
       (SELECT COUNT(group_members.user_id) FROM group_members 
         WHERE group_members.group_id = "groups".id) members_count
FROM "groups";
```

#### How to get it in Exposed

First, we need a wrapper that convert AliasQuery to Expression:

```kotlin
class SubQueryExpression<T>(private val aliasQuery : QueryAlias) : Expression<T>() {
    override fun toQueryBuilder(queryBuilder: QueryBuilder) {
        aliasQuery.describe(TransactionManager.current(), queryBuilder)
    }
}
```

Create subquery:

```kotlin
val membersCount = GroupMembersTable.userId.count()
val subSelect  = GroupMembersTable
                .slice(membersCount)
                .select { GroupMembersTable.groupId eq GroupsTable.id}
val subQuery: QueryAlias = subSelect.alias("members_count")
```

Wrap subquery to expression:

```kotlin
val membersCountExp = SubQueryExpression<Long>(subQuery)
```

Make full query:

```kotlin
val q = GroupsTable
         .slice(GroupsTable.fields + membersCountExp)
         .selectAll()
```

Execute and read calculated value:

```kotlin
q.forEach {
 println(it[membersCountExp])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, that worked, although the first solution is hard to understand and some textual explanation of the logic applied would be appreciated.

I managed to extract data from it:

```kotlin
assertEquals("Manuel", query.andWhere { subQuery[orderCount] eq intLiteral(2) }.first()[Customer.firstName])
```

but I'm unable to extract data from the 2nd solution. Here is what I did:

```kotlin
val orderCount = Order.id.count().alias("OrderCount")

val query = Customer
    .leftJoin(Order, { Customer.id }, { Order.customerId })
    .slice(Customer.firstName, Customer.lastName, orderCount)
    .selectAll()
    .groupBy(Customer.id)

assertEquals("Manuel", query.andWhere { orderCount eq intLiteral(2) }.first()[Customer.firstName])
```

Comment: When you work with `group by` in query you have to use `having` instead of `where` to filter results after grouping. You could read more [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp).

In Exposed it will looks like:
`query.having { orderCount eq 2 }`.

But keep in mind that `andWhere` and `having` mutates Query instance state.

Comment: Thank you, but for it to work I had to move `alias("OrderCount")` from the variable `orderCount` to the place where it was used, i.e. in the `slice` function. @Tapac, now, considering the previous two examples, I got totally confused on how to properly use aliases.

Comment: To "extact data" from Query result you may use pure Kotlin: query.first { it[orderCount] == 2L }[Customer.firstName]

Comment: `andWhere` as well as `having` are not "extracting data" from query result, but keep constructing SQL-query. The `having` clause was added to SQL because the `where` clause could not be used with aggregate functions. Columns aliases in `having` clause can't be used too (because clause is related to aggregate function, not column) - this is a restriction of SQL, not Exposed. But generally you may use `where` in query when you have `group by` clause (or both `where` and `having`). See https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp

Comment: To convert ExpressionAlias back to Expression use its `delegate` field: `assertEquals("Manuel", query.having { orderCount.delegate eq intLiteral(2) }.first()[Customer.firstName])`

Answer (score 0):

I have found this other way, using the abstract Function class and creating an internal Query. You can check this post where it is explained better

https://medium.com/@jassielcastro/exposed-in-action-customizing-results-with-subqueries-in-ktor-e0eda69a7b31

```html
open class SubCountQueryFunction<T : Table>(
    private val table: Alias<T>,
    private val count: String = "*",
    private val where: SqlExpressionBuilder.() -> Op<Boolean>
) : Function<Long>(LongColumnType()) {

    /**
     * Return example: 
     * (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table as TableAlias WHERE TableAlias.id = 1)
     */
    override fun toQueryBuilder(queryBuilder: QueryBuilder): Unit = queryBuilder {
        append('(')
        append("SELECT COUNT($count) FROM ${table.delegate.tableName} as ${table.alias} ")
        append("WHERE ${SqlExpressionBuilder.where()}")
        append(')')
    }
}
```